# Data is not saving in MYSQL database using NodeJS, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, bcrypt

When I am submitting the form "Query Error" popup is showing... Data is not saving in database.

API

```js
router.post("/add_customer", (req, res) => {
  const sql = `INSERT INTO customer (name, mobile, email, address, state, city, policytype, insurer, renewdate) VALUES (?)`;
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ Status: false, Error: "Query Error" });
    const values = [
      req.body.name,
      req.body.mobile,
      req.body.email,
      req.body.address,
      req.body.state,
      req.body.city,
      req.body.policytype,
      req.body.insurer,
      req.file.filename,
      req.body.renewdate,
    ];
    con.query(sql, [values], (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ Status: false, Error: err });
      return res.json({ Status: true });
    });
  });
});
```

AXIOS API -

```js
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({
  name: "",
  mobile: "",
  email: "",
  address: "",
  state: "",
  city: "",
  policytype: "",
  insurer: "",
  renewdate: "",
});

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", customer.name);
  formData.append("mobile", customer.mobile);
  formData.append("email", customer.email);
  formData.append("address", customer.address);
  formData.append("state", customer.state);
  formData.append("city", customer.city);
  formData.append("policytype", customer.policytype);
  formData.append("insurer", customer.insurer);
  formData.append("renewdate", customer.renewdate);

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/employee/add_customer", formData)
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.data.Status) {
        navigate("/employeedashboard/customer");
      } else {
        alert(result.data.Error);
      }
    });
};
```

Code is in NodeJs & ReactJs

Comment: What is the error you are getting, try share the error msg. Try to print the SQL qeruy formed with the prepared statement values. Copy it and run it in backend to see the issue.

Comment: If you're literally getting _"Query Error"_, then it means your `bcrypt.hash()` is failing. Why aren't you even logging the error? How are you supposed to know what failed if you don't look? `if (err) { console.error("hash failed", err); return res.sendStatus(500); }`

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with `FormData` unless you're trying to send files. You need special middleware like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle `mutlipart/form-data` request bodies.

The problem is that because you have no such middleware, all your `req.body` properties will be `undefined`. This is causing `bcrypt.hash()` to fail.

Simply add JSON handling middleware to your Express app if you haven't already...

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

and send the data as JSON...

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/employee/add_customer", customer)
```

---

Further advice... **NEVER** ignore errors. At the very least, log them

```js
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("hash failed for", req.body.password, err);
    return res.status(400).send("Password could not be hashed");
  }
```